# How to pass info from one job to another

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job (jobA) which calls another one (jobB).

I have a string which is generated in a batch file called by jobA which needs to be passed into jobB.

How can I get that string out of jobA and into jobB?

Might it be possible to, say, set an environment variable to that string, somehow turn it into a jenkins parameter, and then pass that parameter into jobB?

Currently, my only other idea is to write the string out to a file in jobA, save that file as an artifact, pass that artifact into jobB, and then have jobB read that file.  That seems a really kludgey way to do it, though.

It seems that there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use Jenkins **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**.

Then, you can for example set jobB's parameters based on a properties file generated by jobA.

Comment: That plugin's page says "This plugin lets you trigger new builds when your build has completed, with various ways of specifying parameters for the new build."

Does that mean that this plugin does not work for subprojects that are launched from a build step (instead of ones that are launched after the build is completed)?

Comment: Actually this plugin does support the scenario you described. To do that add a new build step of type "Trigger/call builds on other projects", then choose click the "Add Parameters" combo and choose "Parameters from properties file" in the exact same way you'd to it as a post-build step.